# JavaDocs: How to Create a Custom Markup

Tags: java, android, kotlin, integration-testing, javadoc

I am creating a suite of instrumentation tests, written in Kotlin, that will hit numerous Web APIs. I plan to implement these tests into our CI/CD process. With that being said, I would like to add detailed documentation to each test for maintainability, verifying scenario coverage, etc.

Currently, I am using JavaDocs for documentation; however, there are only a handful of markups, most of which do not pertain to testing documentation (@return, @see, @author, @param, @exception, @sample, @simple, @since, @suppress, and @throws). As a result, I was wondering if there is a way to create custom markup and implement them into my documentation? For example, @scenario or @expected?

Comment: They're not annotations. It's just the mark-up of JavaDoc, and both happen to be prefixed by an @. You can use whatever custom markup you want, but any JavaDoc processors will probably just ignore it

Comment: I'd also argue that a good test should be self-documenting. I don't personally see much value to what you're planning on doing.

Comment: Michael, thank you for the markup clarification. Currently, I use @scenario in my documentation, and it is ignored by the JavaDoc processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a custom doclet. See ['Creating and handling custom tags'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html)

> Suppose, for example, that you want use a custom tag, say `@mytag`, in
>   your documentation comments in addition to the standard tags like
>   `@param` and `@return`. To make use of the information in your custom
>   tags, you need to have your doclet use instances of Tag that represent
>   your custom tags. One of the easiest ways to do that is to use the
>   tags(String) method of Doc or one of Doc's subclasses. This method
>   returns an array of Tag objects representing any tags whose name
>   matches the string argument. For example, if method is an instance of
>   MethodDoc, then
>
> ```
> method.tags("mytag")
> ```
>
> would return an array of Tag
>   objects representing any `@mytag` tags in the method's documentation
>   comment. You can then access the information in your `@mytag` tags with
>   Tag's text method. That method returns a string representing the
>   content of the tag which you can parse or use as needed. For example,
>   if a documentation comment contained one of your custom tags like
>   this:
>
> ```
> @mytag Some dummy text.
> ```
>
> then the text method would return the
>   string "Some dummy text.". Here's a standalone doclet (not a subclass
>   of the standard doclet) that uses these ideas to print out the text
>   associated with all instances of a specified tag that it finds in
>   method comments. It could be extended to find all instances of that
>   tag in all comments.
>
> ```
> import com.sun.javadoc.*;
>
> public class ListTags {
>     public static boolean start(RootDoc root){ 
>         String tagName = "mytag";
>         writeContents(root.classes(), tagName);
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     private static void writeContents(ClassDoc[] classes, String tagName) {
>         for (int i=0; i < classes.length; i++) {
>             boolean classNamePrinted = false;
>             MethodDoc[] methods = classes[i].methods();
>             for (int j=0; j < methods.length; j++) {
>                 Tag[] tags = methods[j].tags(tagName);
>                 if (tags.length > 0) {
>                     if (!classNamePrinted) {
>                         System.out.println("\n" + classes[i].name() + "\n");
>                         classNamePrinted = true;
>                     }
>                     System.out.println(methods[j].name());
>                     for (int k=0; k < tags.length; k++) {
>                         System.out.println("   " + tags[k].name() + ": " 
>                         + tags[k].text());
>                     }
>                 } 
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The tag for which this doclet searches is specified by the variable tagName. The value of the tagName string can be any tag name,
>   custom or standard. This doclet writes to standard out, but its output
>   format could be modified, for example, to write HTML output to a file.

Comment: Michael, thank you for taking the time out of your day to provide some valuable insight.